# How to show posts ONLY in SUBcategories using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress and I want my posts be shown only in my subcategories. How can I do that?

Right now my Raven posts are being shown under Birds as well. But I only want them to be shown under Ravens-and-crows.

I dont want ANY of my posts to be on this page: http://origami.directory/birds/

Comment: `$query = new WP_Query( 'category__in=4' );` where `4` is the ID of you category of choice (in your case, I guess its Raven), should do the trick, right?

Comment: But I have a lot of subcategories. I just want the posts to not show up in the top categories. If I have a top category with a sub category - Lets say they are Birds -> Ravens. And I cross the box at raven but not birds. Then that post will still be seen at birds. Isnt there an automatic way to do this? to stop making top categories show any posts?